# Transferring data from elasticsearch to influx

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, influxdb, elasticsearch-py, kapacitor

I am trying to send data from `Elasticsearch` to `Influxdb`. Is there any other way to do this except writing plugins and configuration files. I am new to both these databases, and trying to understand the overall picture.

Also, am I right in understanding that `Kapacitor` processes influx data and then sends it to `Kafka` for streaming? Or should I stream data using Kapacitor only?

I am trying to learn all these new technologies in as short time frame, and all the new terminologies have got me confused. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch is a search engine, not a database. InfluxDB is a time series data. I did't understand why you need to transfer data from search results to a time series database.

Kapacitor can process data in 2 different ways. Either in batch mode or in streaming mode. Assume some application streaming sensor data(or some time series data) to InfluxDb. You can set Kapacitor to process that data as soon it is available in InfluxDB by setting kapacitor in streaming mode. Or in case you need to process data from InfluxDB every 2 hour, you can configure that job as  batch job. Once you process the data, Kapacitor can persist the data in InfluxDB. Or in case you need to stream the data to Kafka, Kpacitor has a Kafka plugin. Please note Kapacitor has more plugins than I mentioned in my answer.